# how to stub a method on an object using sinon.js to return particular value?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I try to stub getter method on some object using the following approach:

`const stub = sinon.stub(store, 'isBriefType').returns(true);`

then I try to check whether I get stubbed value:

`expect(store.isBriefType).toEqual(true);`

but the value I get as a result of calling `store.isBriedType` is actual result of the actual method, not stubbed one.

what do I do wrong?

Comment: From what is shown here, it should be working as you expect... Can you show a bit more code? Is there a chance the stub is being reset in some hook or something like that?

Comment: actually, the code is perfectly fine. I did some mistake in another part which caused me think problem is here

Comment: not sure whether I should close/delete this question or leave as it is because it contains some code which can be useful for someone